# WPF Binding ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So I am currently trying to learn WPF with MVVM and I was following some tutorials online. Now that I have a simple Project, I tried to do it on my own but somehow the ListBox stays empty. It doesn't get bound to the ViewModel, I think. What am I missing here?

ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> Personen { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public PersonViewModel()
    {
        Personen.Add(new Person { Vorname = "My", Nachname = "Name", Email = "my@name.com" });
        Personen.Add(new Person { Vorname = "Max", Nachname = "Mustermann", Email = "max@mustermann.de" });
        Personen.Add(new Person { Vorname = "John", Nachname = "Doe", Email = "john@doe.com" });
        Personen.Add(new Person { Vorname = "Jane", Nachname = "Doe", Email = "jane@doe.com" });
    }
}
```

}

Also, I'm setting my DataContext like this:

```
public PersonenView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new ViewModel.PersonViewModel();
}
```

Comment: As a note, you should generally not explicitly set a UserControl's DataContext as you do in the PersonView constructor. UserControls do usually inherit their DataContext from their parent element (e.g. a Window or Page) and then either directly bind their child elements to properties of the inherited DataContext, or have their own dependency properties bound to properties of the DataContext object.

Comment: @Clemens do you mean in my `MainWindow` View? I show my usercontrol like this: `<views:PersonenView x:Name="PersonenViewControl" Margin="20" />`.  Do you mean I should set the DataContext Property inside this xaml? How would I do that?

Comment: The MainWindow would usually also have a view model, which would have a PersonViewModel property (say `PersonVM`). You would then set the PersonView's DataContext like `<views:PersonenView DataContext="{Binding PersonVM}"/>`, which would not work when PersonView had explicitly set its DataContext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to give a public accessor to ObservableCollection Personen in your ViewModel.

You should also make the property readonly (or fire a property change notification from its setter):

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> Personen { get; }
    = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

Comment: @sLw You can even type "propfull" and then tab, to create full public property with setter and getter

Comment: @Ugur that's what I am doing normally, see my Model. But with this Collection I was going for an auto property, manually. That's why I forgot to set it public

Comment: @Clemens ah, nice tip.